# Python packages and imports - clarification needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

The import function of Python still confuses me sometimes. Here's an example:

My project has the following package structure:

```
Project/
    src/
        example/
            __init__.py
            an_example.py
        top/
            __init__.py
            lin/
                __init__.py
                factory.py
```

In `an_example.py`, I'd like to write

```
from top import lin
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = lin.factory.AClass()
```

However, this fails with:

```
    a = lin.factory.AClass()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'factory'
```

`an_example.py` works when written like this:

```
from top.lin import factory
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = factory.AClass()
```

Can you explain to me why it is wrong to write the import statement like the first version? I'd prefer a fully qualified name like `lin.factory.AClass` to `factory.AClass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because, unless you tell `lin` to import `factory` in `__init__.py`, then `factory` is not in the `lin` namespace.

E.g:

Presume your existing project structure, with an_example.py containing:

```
from top import lin

lin.factory.AClass()
```

With `top/lin/__init__.py` blank, we get `ImportError: No module named factory`.

With `top/lin/__init__.py` containing `import top.lin.factory`, we get no error.

When you ask to use `factory.AClass()`, it works because it is defined there. Likewise, you need to define factory in `lin` if you want to use it from there.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware that I have to edit `__init__.py` for nested packages. What is confusing, though, is that I have to import `top.lin.factory` in `top/lin/__init__.py` instead of just `import factory` (which does not work). This means `lin/__init__.py` not only needs to know the contents of `lin/`, but also the package it is contained in (`top`) and has to be edited when moved. Isn't this something that goes against modular design principles?

Comment: @clstaudt Well, only if you want to be able to used them in segments as you have asked to do. You don't *need* to do this to use nested packages. As to the absolute import name, you can, as an alternative, use a relative import (``from . import factory``).